# multiple mobile apps connecting to one Meteor app at backend

Tags: android, mobile, meteor

I have been working with Meteor for the past 5 months and have been really impressed with the framework and the community. I am looking for some guidance or pointers from the community.

I am currently working on a project and looking at a possibility of creating two mobile apps created using meteor framework that are served by a single Meteor application at the backend. One mobile app would be a paid version and the other free. The free version will not have any login screens.

I have dirty solution - that is to clone the same meteor app and customise it to serve for each mobile app but use the same mongodb backend. This currently works but I am guessing it will become a pain to maintain in the long run.

I am sure there is a more elegant/better solution that can be done by passing parameters at build time for the mobile apps. Any suggestions please?

Comment: You can probably do this using a package-based architecture with multiple configuration files (include/exclude certain source files in the main package file based on configuration parameters), but why not use a paid subscription with RBAC for this and have a single app? Seems like a much cleaner solution to me.

Comment: I agree Paid subscription with RBAC is better option. But I am curious and I am sure my use case will be a need. I am not sure of changing configurations during build will help, the hot code push feature of meteor will push any changes to the base app to mobile app.